# Ignore files in Mercurial using Glob syntax

Tags: regex, mercurial, cvs, glob, hgignore

I'm using Mercurial and I have a following structure:

```
files
   test
       demo.jpg
       video.flv
       video.doc

   sport
       demo2.jpg
       picture.jpg
       text.txt
demo3.jpg
demofile3.doc
```

I want to make a glob filter that only ignore all "jpg" files in all directory that are children of "files" directory

I tried with files/*.jpg but it doesn't work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Regexp solution

This works for me ..

```
syntax: regexp
files/.*/.*jpg
```

Your own solution looks more like a glob. The trick with that is to use the ** syntax to allow for sub directories. See this ...

#### Glob solution

This glob works for me too

```
**/files/**/*.jpg
```

#### Comments

Personally I'd always go with the glob syntx for this kind of problem. Once you know about the ** syntax, it's easier than a regexp to follow what the pattern is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but I have one more thing. When I use regexp it ignore the files in other directory that start or has word files in they names. But i want that regexp match only folder files. How can I do that?

Comment: @Danillo. I'll take a look and get back to you asap.

Comment: @Daniilo, I've tried reproducing your scenario but it seems to work for me ...

touch files/test/demo.jpg
touch anfiles/test/files.doc

>hg stat

? anfiles/test/files.doc

Answer (score 12):

If you are happy to ignore "all JPG files inside any directory named `files`", then use

```
syntax: glob
files/**.jpg
```

See `hg help patterns` which explains that `**` is a glob operator that spans directory separators. This means that the file

```
 files/test/demo.jpg
```

is matched by `files/**.jpg`.

However, note that glob patterns [are **not** rooted](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html). This means that a file named

```
 test/files/demo.jpg
```

will also be ignored since it matches the pattern after you remove the `test/` prefix.

You need to use a regular expression if you are concerned with this. In that syntax, the pattern reads

```
syntax: regex
^files/.*\.jpg
```

I would normally not worry about rooting the pattern -- I prefer the simplicity of the glob patterns. But it's nice to know that you can root a ignore pattern if you really have to.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be glob syntax? If you use regex syntax, `files/.*\.jpg` should work.